# What is the "built in TextView widget android:text1" and the "ListView widget android:id/list"?

Tags: android

An Android tutorial guide uses the following XML definitions and quotes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

> This XML uses the built-in Android ListView widget android:id/list.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true />
```

> This XML uses the built-in Android TextView widget android:text1.

First of all, I am used to seeing `id` properties defined like this:

```
android:id="@+id/list1"
```

What does it mean to use `@android:id/list` instead?

Second, what does `built-in ... widget` mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are ids defined in the Android SDK and which are used in some of the layout XML files provided by the Android SDK. You can refer directly to those ids in XML (e.g. `android:id="@android:id/text1"`) or in Java (e.g. `findViewById(android.R.id.text1)` -- notice the fully-qualified name in java.

Some of these ids have special meaning in certain contexts. For example, if you are extending `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`, you must use `android:id="@android:id/list"` because those classes look for a ListView with that specific ID as part of their implementation. (If you don't provide a layout at all, those classes default to a layout with just a ListView in it.)

Note that you can still use these IDs outside of these special cases -- there's nothing preventing you from giving any view `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Answer (score 0):

built-in ... widget means that you don't need any special library in your project to use this widget(it is already built-in in the android sdk).

Answer (score 0):

Android Default Text View is for when you don't want user defined explicate Text View with a different properties than you can just use it. it gives Simple and best representation
I have one Expandable list view so rather than define different resource file for just a text view i always use Default Text view.

Here i am giving some Default views which i prefer to use :

Default Text View  : findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
ListIteam Text View : (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
Expandable ListIteam Text View :(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, null)